# Is there benefit of having faster master node in hadoop cluster?

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing, hadoop2

I have recently built a multi-node Hadoop 2.5.0 cluster using few ARM development boards, and I can not decide if I should use same type of board as master, if I should use faster arm board as master, or even if I should use a desktop to be master to manage slave nodes?

Is there any benefit of having master node faster than the slave nodes in the same cluster?

Besides benefits of increased RAM, does increased CPU performance of master node matters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namenode/Jobtracker hardware specifications must be relational to worker nodes. (something like [this](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/08/how-to-select-the-right-hardware-for-your-new-hadoop-cluster/) might help)

But I don't recall any recommendation about having more powerful master nodes. They don't need to have extra Ram/HDD/CPU power. Actually you can save money by using less power in master nodes without losing much performance. (Do not forget **relational**)